# how to add my database on a html table using session variables in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, uitableview, session-variables

I have a website that has multiple users that submit some requests, So each user will have his own Requests table that has been made. my issue is I'm trying to show the requests for every user in a table by using the session variables to get the name of the user and match it with the request table but it dose not work.

```
    $userin= $_SESSION['username'];
$req = "SELECT * FROM request_table where r_status='pending' AND requester = 'max';";
$request_table = $conn->query($req);
```

it works if I out ( Max ) only but when I put it as a session variable or as $userin it dose not work and I get this error :

```
    Notice: Trying to get property 'num_rows' of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\website\b_table.php on line 54.
```

Below is my code for the table :

```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
   <body>
<h1 align="center">Table</h1>
<table border="5" align="center" style="line-height:20px;">
<tr>
<th>Request ID</th>
<th>Requester name</th>
<th>Customer name</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Submition Date</th>
<th>Request Status</th>
<th>link</th>
</tr>
<?php
//Fetch Data form database
 if($request_table->num_rows > 0){
 while($view_request = $request_table->fetch_assoc()){
 ?>
 <tr>
 <td><?php echo $view_request['request_id']; ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $view_request['requester']; ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $view_request['customer_name']; ?></td>
 <td><?php echo "Site A is:". $view_request['site_a']. ",<br> Site B is: ".$view_request['site_b']. ",<br>NO. Of links =:".$view_request['no_oflinks']; ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $view_request['sub_date']; ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $view_request['request_status']; ?></td>
 <form action="view_request.php" method="GET"><td><button type="vieww" name="vieww" value= <?php echo $view_request['request_id']; ?>> View </button></td></form>
 </tr>
 <?php
 }
}
else
{
 ?>
 <tr>
 <th colspan="7">No Data availabe</th>
 </tr>
 <?php
}
$conn->close();
?>
</table>
``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOHOX.jpg
```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Comment: Please post your database structure.This error is occurred in column names

Comment: Your `$mysqli->query()` function returns `false` because it failed, you should have put this line in the question. Do `var_dump($userin);exit;` to see what is in this variable that made the query fall.

Comment: Accountant, where exactly should I write that code, I'm still new to this field

Comment: Do `var_dump($userin);exit;` right after `$userin= $_SESSION['username'];` to see what is the `$userin` variable is actually is, and why it caused the query to fall.

Answer (score 0):

you can do some debugging and testing.
like check if session variable is set or not like :

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
 $userin= $_SESSION['username'];
} 
else{
   die("Session user name wasn't set");
}
```

and for the query

```
$req = "SELECT * FROM request_table where r_status='pending' AND requester = '$userin';"
```

for more debugging and testing , you can use vardump to check if data is present or not like : vardump($request_table);
hope it helps you in some way...

hope it helps.